# Question on the definition for the zeros of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

My question arises from a kid's task, finding the zeros of $e^{-1/x}$ on the complex plane. We know that $e^{-1/x}$ should not have any zeros, but $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}e^{-1/x}=0$ which can be cast as $e^{-1/0^{+}}=0$ symbolically, i.e., $0^{+}$ behaves like a zero, even though $0^{+}\neq 0$. My question is if $0^{+}$ can be regarded as the zero of function $e^{-1/x}$. Generally, for any types of discontinuity, if the limit of function tends to zero at certain value $x_0$, could we say that $x_0$ is the zero of that function?

Comment: $e^{-1/x}$ is not defined at $0$ and it has no zeros in its domain.

Comment: You've already answered this yourself: “we know that $e^{-1/x}$ should not have any zeros”.

Comment: We can’t have a definition for such “zeros” since such limit doesn’t exist, the left limit is not equal to the right limit, it is a essential singularity actually.

Comment: *from a kid's task* --- This is a really gifted kid!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function such as $f(x) = e^{-1/x}$, which is not defined at $0$, you are certainly free to define a new function

$\overline{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
                  e^{-1/x} & x \neq 0 \\
                  0 & x = 0
              \end{cases}$

So in this case, $0$ is not a zero of $f$, but it *is* a zero of $\overline{f}$. The function $\overline{f}$ has the nice property that it is right-continuous at $x = 0$, but this is unrelated to its zeros. The fact that $0$ is a zero of $\overline{f}$ is simply by definition.